# Django error when accessing many to many through field of not managed model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting this weird error which I am unable to sort out myself:

`'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'`

Relevant parts of code are these:

**models.py:**

```
class Section(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    

    child=models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        through='SectionParent',
        through_fields = ('parent_section_id', 'section_id'),

    )


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'section'

class SectionParent(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="m2m_child")
    parent_section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="m2m_parent")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'section_parent'
```

**views.py:**

```
def navigation(request, section_id=None):

    # Load species if no id is provided
    if not section_id:
        sections = Section.objects.using('app-db').filter(type=SectionType.speciesCategory.value[0]).first()

    # Load children of current section
    else:
        sections = Section.objects.using('app-db').filter(id = section_id).first()


    print(sections.child()) <-------------- ERROR HERE
    return HttpResponse("test")
```

I tried to modify models.py many times including adding related_name, replacing 'self' with 'Section' and other things, changing name of the relationship (child), but nothing seems to sort this out. I think it might be related to the fact that the model runs over existing database (hence managed = false), as I never got such an error with migrations enabled.

Comment: can you check if removing ```through_fields = ('parent_section_id', 'section_id'),``` this helps?

Comment: @shivankgtm no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Getting "no such column: section_parent.id" I guess it tries to find id column which does not exist?

Comment: Hmm, what's happening is intresting or I might have not the right information. What I can suggest is using ```Section Parent``` class only and remove the ```child``` field.

Comment: But I need a many to many relationship, I cannot do that that way unless I misunderstand something?

Comment: you can remove the child field. Your ```SectionParent``` model is exactly what that ```child``` field would have created in DB. you can update the ```related_name```(s) also in your SectionParent model for better readability

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241880/discussion-between-shivankgtm-and-danielius).